# how to Destroy and Reload notebook tab

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, jupyter-notebook

Can anyone help me out delete one notebook tab and then reload it.

I have this that destroy the tab but cant seem to reload it after.

I need to reload the tab to simulate a start again, deleting all that was done and restarting the tab

Why is it not reloading?

```
from formularios import tabControlmain
for item in tabControlmain.winfo_children():
    if str(item) == (tabControlmain.select()):
        item.destroy() # this destroys tabmain1
        return

tabmain1 = ttk.Frame(tabControlmain)# creates tabmain1
tabControlmain.add(tabmain1, text='Testing Tool')
tabControlmain.pack(expand=True, fill="both")
makeformtestcond()# this runs the function that populate the tabmain1
```

Comment: Provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `item.hide(index)`
And later use `item.add` again.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
root = Tk()

def add():
    notebook1.add(frame1, text="Tab")
def remove():
    notebook1.hide(0)
    root.after(2000, add)
frame1 = Frame(root)
frame1.pack()
notebook1 = ttk.Notebook(root)
notebook1.pack()

notebook1.add(frame1, text="Tab")

root.after(2000, remove)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: thanks, but i need it to reload again in order to "forget" what was done and start over